# cant import my game file to be able to run

Tags: python, pygame

I'm currently coding a game that has a menu and then once the user clicks start to game the game plays, so far I've coded my menu and the game is almost done but I'm not sure how to connect them? I have created 4 files, one which runs the program, one with the menu class, one which is called the game and the last one which is shapes.Shapes are the game that I want to start once the user clicks start game. I think my problem may be that I haven't used a class in the Shapes file but I am not sure?

I will leave the code for the files below.

Runs program:`
from game import Game
import Shapes

```
g = Game()

while g.running:
   g.curr_menu.display_menu()
   g.game_loop()
```

Menu File:

```
import pygame

class Menu():
    def __init__(self, game):
        self.game = game
        self.mid_w, self.mid_h = self.game.DISPLAY_W / 2, self.game.DISPLAY_H / 2
        self.run_display = True
        self.cursor_rect = pygame.Rect(0, 0, 20, 20)
        self.offset = - 100

    def draw_cursor(self):
        self.game.draw_text('*', 25, self.cursor_rect.x, self.cursor_rect.y)

    def blit_screen(self):
        self.game.window.blit(self.game.display, (0, 0))
        pygame.display.update()
        self.game.reset_keys()

class MainMenu(Menu):
    def __init__(self, game):
        Menu.__init__(self, game)
        self.state = "Start"
        self.startx, self.starty = self.mid_w, self.mid_h + 40
        self.optionsx, self.optionsy = self.mid_w, self.mid_h + 78
        self.creditsx, self.creditsy = self.mid_w, self.mid_h + 120
        self.cursor_rect.midtop = (self.startx + self.offset, self.starty)

    def display_menu(self):
        self.run_display = True
        while self.run_display:
            self.game.check_events()
            self.check_input()
            self.game.display.fill(self.game.BLACK)
            self.game.draw_text('Main Menu', 48, self.game.DISPLAY_W / 2, self.game.DISPLAY_H / 2 - 20)
            self.game.draw_text("Start Training", 28, self.startx, self.starty)
            self.game.draw_text("Options", 28, self.optionsx, self.optionsy)
            self.game.draw_text("Credits", 28, self.creditsx, self.creditsy)
            self.draw_cursor()
            self.blit_screen()


    def move_cursor(self):
        if self.game.DOWN_KEY:
            if self.state == 'Start':
                self.cursor_rect.midtop = (self.optionsx + self.offset, self.optionsy)
                self.state = 'Options'
            elif self.state == 'Options':
                self.cursor_rect.midtop = (self.creditsx + self.offset, self.creditsy)
                self.state = 'Credits'
            elif self.state == 'Credits':
                self.cursor_rect.midtop = (self.startx + self.offset, self.starty)
                self.state = 'Start'
        elif self.game.UP_KEY:
            if self.state == 'Start':
                self.cursor_rect.midtop = (self.creditsx + self.offset, self.creditsy)
                self.state = 'Credits'
            elif self.state == 'Options':
                self.cursor_rect.midtop = (self.startx + self.offset, self.starty)
                self.state = 'Start'
            elif self.state == 'Credits':
                self.cursor_rect.midtop = (self.optionsx + self.offset, self.optionsy)
                self.state = 'Options'

    def check_input(self):
        self.move_cursor()
        if self.game.START_KEY:
            if self.state == 'Start':
                self.game.playing = True
            elif self.state == 'Options':
                self.game.curr_menu = self.game.options
            elif self.state == 'Credits':
                self.game.curr_menu = self.game.credits
            self.run_display = False

class OptionsMenu(Menu):
    def __init__(self, game):
        Menu.__init__(self, game)
        self.state = 'Progress'
        self.volx, self.voly = self.mid_w, self.mid_h + 20
        self.controlsx, self.controlsy = self.mid_w, self.mid_h + 60
        self.cursor_rect.midtop = (self.volx + self.offset, self.voly)

    def display_menu(self):
        self.run_display = True
        while self.run_display:
            self.game.check_events()
            self.check_input()
            self.game.display.fill((0, 0, 0))
            self.game.draw_text('Options', 48, self.game.DISPLAY_W / 2, self.game.DISPLAY_H / 2 - 30)
            self.game.draw_text("Progress", 28, self.volx, self.voly)
            self.game.draw_text("Controls", 28, self.controlsx, self.controlsy)
            self.draw_cursor()
            self.blit_screen()

    def check_input(self):
        if self.game.BACK_KEY:
            self.game.curr_menu = self.game.main_menu
            self.run_display = False
        elif self.game.UP_KEY or self.game.DOWN_KEY:
            if self.state == 'Progress':
                self.state = 'Controls'
                self.cursor_rect.midtop = (self.controlsx + self.offset, self.controlsy)
            elif self.state == 'Controls':
                self.state = 'Progress'
                self.cursor_rect.midtop = (self.volx + self.offset, self.voly)
        elif self.game.START_KEY:
            # TO-DO: Create a Volume Menu and a Controls Menu
            pass

class CreditsMenu(Menu):
    def __init__(self, game):
        Menu.__init__(self, game)

    def display_menu(self):
        self.run_display = True
        while self.run_display:
            self.game.check_events()
            if self.game.START_KEY or self.game.BACK_KEY:
                self.game.curr_menu = self.game.main_menu
                self.run_display = False
            self.game.display.fill(self.game.BLACK)
            self.game.draw_text('Credits', 28, self.game.DISPLAY_W / 2, self.game.DISPLAY_H / 2 - 20)
            self.game.draw_text('Made by Dylan Jackson', 20, self.game.DISPLAY_W / 2, self.game.DISPLAY_H / 2 + 10)
            self.blit_screen()
```

Game file:

```
import pygame
import os
from menu import *


class Game():
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.init()
        self.running, self.playing = True, False
        self.UP_KEY, self.DOWN_KEY, self.START_KEY, self.BACK_KEY = False, False, False, False
        self.DISPLAY_W, self.DISPLAY_H = 700, 600
        self.display = pygame.Surface((self.DISPLAY_W,self.DISPLAY_H))
        self.window = pygame.display.set_mode(((self.DISPLAY_W,self.DISPLAY_H)))
        self.font_name = 'Font.ttf'
        #self.font_name = pygame.font.get_default_font()
        self.BLACK, self.WHITE = (0, 0, 0), (255, 255, 255)
        self.main_menu = MainMenu(self)
        self.options = OptionsMenu(self)
        self.credits = CreditsMenu(self)
        self.curr_menu = self.main_menu


    def game_loop(self):
        while self.playing:
            self.check_events()
            if self.START_KEY:
                self.playing= True

            self.display.fill(self.BLACK)
            self.draw_text('Thanks for Playing', 30, self.DISPLAY_W/2, self.DISPLAY_H/2)
            self.window.blit(self.display, (0,0))
            pygame.display.update()
            self.reset_keys()



    def check_events(self):
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                self.running, self.playing = False, False
                self.curr_menu.run_display = False
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
                    self.START_KEY = True
                if event.key == pygame.K_BACKSPACE:
                    self.BACK_KEY = True
                if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    self.DOWN_KEY = True
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    self.UP_KEY = True

    def reset_keys(self):
        self.UP_KEY, self.DOWN_KEY, self.START_KEY, self.BACK_KEY = False, False, False, False

    def draw_text(self, text, size, x, y ):
        font = pygame.font.Font(self.font_name,size)
        text_surface = font.render(text, True, self.WHITE)
        text_rect = text_surface.get_rect()
        text_rect.center = (x,y)
        self.display.blit(text_surface,text_rect)
```

Shapes file:

```
import pygame
import os
import time
import random

WHITE = (250, 250, 250)
WIDTH, HEIGHT = 750, 600
WIN = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("Eye Reaction App !")
FPS = 60
IMAGE_WIDTH, IMAGE_HEIGHT = 60, 50

GOLD_STAR_IMAGE = pygame.image.load(
    os.path.join('Assets', 'gold_star.png'))
GOLD_STAR = pygame.transform.scale(GOLD_STAR_IMAGE, (IMAGE_WIDTH, IMAGE_HEIGHT))

GREEN_TRIANGLE_IMAGE = pygame.image.load(
    os.path.join('Assets', 'green_triangle.png'))
GREEN_TRIANGLE = pygame.transform.scale(GREEN_TRIANGLE_IMAGE, (IMAGE_WIDTH, IMAGE_HEIGHT))

LIGHT_BLUE_RECTANGLE_IMAGE = pygame.image.load(
    os.path.join('Assets', 'light_blue_rectangle.png'))
LIGHT_BLUE_RECTANGLE = pygame.transform.scale(LIGHT_BLUE_RECTANGLE_IMAGE, (IMAGE_WIDTH, IMAGE_HEIGHT))

ORANGE_SQUARE_IMAGE = pygame.image.load(
    os.path.join('Assets', 'orange_square.png'))
ORANGE_SQUARE = pygame.transform.scale(ORANGE_SQUARE_IMAGE, (IMAGE_WIDTH, IMAGE_HEIGHT))

PURPLE_HEXAGON_IMAGE = pygame.image.load(
    os.path.join('Assets', 'purple_hexagon.png'))
PURPLE_HEXAGON = pygame.transform.scale(PURPLE_HEXAGON_IMAGE, (IMAGE_WIDTH, IMAGE_HEIGHT))

RED_CIRCLE_IMAGE = pygame.image.load(
    os.path.join('Assets', 'red_circle.png'))
RED_CIRCLE = pygame.transform.scale(RED_CIRCLE_IMAGE, (IMAGE_WIDTH, IMAGE_HEIGHT))


def draw_window_one(star, triangle, rectangle, square, hexagon, circle):
    WIN.fill(WHITE)
    WIN.blit(GOLD_STAR, (star.x, star.y))
    WIN.blit(GREEN_TRIANGLE, (triangle.x, triangle.y))
    WIN.blit(LIGHT_BLUE_RECTANGLE, (rectangle.x, rectangle.y))
    WIN.blit(ORANGE_SQUARE, (square.x, square.y))
    WIN.blit(PURPLE_HEXAGON, (hexagon.x, hexagon.y))
    WIN.blit(RED_CIRCLE, (circle.x, circle.y))

    pygame.display.update()


def main():
    star = pygame.Rect(75, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT)
    triangle = pygame.Rect(575, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT)
    rectangle = pygame.Rect(175, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT)
    square = pygame.Rect(275, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT)
    hexagon = pygame.Rect(375, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT)
    circle = pygame.Rect(475, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT)

    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    run = True
    while run:
        clock.tick(FPS)
        if star.y > HEIGHT:
            star.y = -1
        elif triangle.y > HEIGHT:
            triangle.y = -1
        elif rectangle.y > HEIGHT:
            rectangle.y = -1
        elif square.y > HEIGHT:
            square.y = -1
        elif hexagon.y > HEIGHT:
            hexagon.y = -1
        elif circle.y > HEIGHT:
            circle.y = -1
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False
        star.y += 2
        triangle.y += 2
        rectangle.y += 2
        square.y += 2
        hexagon.y += 2
        circle.y += 2
        draw_window_one(star, triangle, rectangle, square, hexagon, circle)

    pygame.quit()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all, to run the program is needed the assets folder.

Even so, I think your main problem is that you are doing

```
import Shapes
```

which does not exist, I recommend you import it this way

```
from shapes import *
```

this means that the file shape will be executed. and you will be able to use all the functions and variables declared.

if you do

```
import shapes
```

to use your functions you will need to call them like this

```
shapes.draw_window_one(...)
```